# Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
blobType: string = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
  cols = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5']
  data = [
    { col1: "a1", col2: "b1", col3: "c1", col4: "d1", col5: "e1" },
    { col1: "a2", col2: "b2", col3: "c2", col4: "d2", col5: "e2" },
    { col1: "a3", col2: "b3", col3: "c3", col4: "d3", col5: "e3" },
    { col1: "a4", col2: "b4", col3: "c4", col4: "d4", col5: "e4" },
    { col1: "a5", col2: "b5", col3: "c5", col4: "d5", col5: "e5" }
  ]
```

This is my method

```
exportToExcel() {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.creator = 'Web';
    workbook.lastModifiedBy = 'Web';
    workbook.created = new Date();
    workbook.modified = new Date();
    workbook.addWorksheet(this.sName, { views: [{state: 'frozen', ySplit: 3,
                                                  xSplit: 2, activeCell: 'A1', showGridLines: false}] });
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    let head1 = ['Exported Data'];
    sheet.addRow(head1);
    sheet.addRow('');
    sheet.getRow(3).values = this.cols;
    sheet.columns = [
      { key: 'col1' },
      { key: 'col2' },
      { key: 'col3' },
      { key: 'col4' },
      { key: 'col5' }
    ];
    sheet.addRows(this.data);
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      const blob = new Blob([data], { type: this.blobType });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = this.excelFileName;
      a.click();
    })
  }
}
```

Error:

> Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.   Type 'Buffer' is
> not assignable to type 'Blob'.
> Property 'size' is missing in type 'Buffer'. [2322] (parameter) data: Excel.Buffer

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: this.blobType });
```

I'm getting error at the above line, did I miss anything ??

Comment: Can you console.log(data) just before that line and add it to your question

Comment: Are you sure it is at this line that you get the error? The error message seems to say it's in Excel.Buffer, which might be some internal method of your excel library, and thus probably not fired from this line where only native code should get used. Which library is it btw? And what browser are you using?

Comment: @Lucho added to my question

Comment: @kaiido Yes I'm, I'm using chrome and Exceljs is the library I'm using, IDE showing error [data] under this.

Comment: Yes but don't post the code with console.log(data), update question with the output of console.log(data)

Comment: @Lucho I'm not able to run the application seems like it is crashed, If I delete above mentioned piece of code from the component I'm able to run the application

Console errors: errors in core.es5.js:1020

1. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

2.ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'AccountModule' in './feature-modules/account/account.module'
Error: Cannot find 'AccountModule' in './feature-modules/account/account.module'

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, not sure where my head is. This is a type issue with ts transpiler problem

Answer (score 28):

This fixed my issue:

```
const blob = new Blob([data as BlobPart], {
  type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the callback into this instead

```
workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data:ArrayBuffer) => {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: this.blobType });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = this.excelFileName;
    a.click();
})
```

**UPDATE**

If you can't cast it like that there is a [pull-request](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/pull/699) waiting for you on this issue, what you can do if you don't want to wait is to manually change it in your index.d.ts imported for excel.js

Comment: after adding data:ArrayBuffer the error is gone but still not able to run the application showing the same errors in the console and I changed index.d.ts manually still no luck :(

Comment: What is the error in console? update it in your post

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data: Blob) => {
            let blob = new Blob([data], { type: this.blobType });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'name_of_the_file.xlsx');
        });
```

Comment: It might be usefull to future users to share why you changed the code like this.

Comment: This is simply wrong, see jingsheng's answer for the correct code. The incoming data type isn't "Blob", "blob" should be a const as it's not changed, and you can't create a Blob without specifying the BlobPart correctly.